# Minimum size of the largest "strong relation group" in a graph

Tags: graph, social-networking

***Strong relation group:*** Each vertice is connected to every other node in the sub-graph.

Given number of **vertices**, and number of **edges**, how one could find (or by which algorithm) the minimum size of the largest *"strong relation group"* in a graph?

For example, if there are **3 vertices** and **2 edges** in a graph, minimum size would be **2** since two of the three nodes would be connected to the same third node, but not to each other. Likewise, when there are **5 vertices** and **7 edges**, only **3** of them would be connected with each other, forming a sub-graph which is a strong relation group.

Thanks.

Comment: This is called the *maximum clique* problem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was searching for..